# How do you map a Series to a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, series

I have created a series from part of a database with the `.value_counts()` function.

```
Series1 = Jim      25
          Albert   36
          Sam      52
          Fiona    65
```

Now I'd like to map it to a dictionary i.e.

```
dic = {'Jim':    25,
       'Albert': 36,
       'Sam':    52,
       'Fiona':  65
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in [`.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) method on your Series.

```
Series1.to_dict()
```